# How to add column-count: 3; when create pdf in laravel 6.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am creating the pdf in Laravel 6.0 here I am failed to divide a div into two columns. Given below the HTML view that I get. But when I convert it in the pdf using

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/pdf');
return view('pdf.myPDF');
return $pdf->download('form.pdf');
```

then it's changed.

After converting it to PDF, I get something else that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy and https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp w3 css

Comment: Can you please add code as well?

Comment: I've cleaned up your question, but it isn't clear what behaviour you want to achieve. Please read [ask].